# Jcrop works only within form tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jcrop

I have been banging my head for almost three days now.THE BELOW CODE WORKS FINE WITHOUT A MASTERPAGE.But when i copy paste the entire thing on the main page(WHICH HAS A MASTERPAGE),it doesnt work and gives out the error "Input string is not in correct format".

**I guess the code works only when i include it in form tag but I cannot have a form tag in a contentplaceholder.How can i work that out?**

The btnUpload works properly but the error pops up when i click btnCrop.
The html is as below :

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div style="width: 540px" runat="server">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload, crop and save image in asp.net</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select image to upload :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgCropped" Width="172px" Height="172px" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" Visible="false" OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCrop" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgToCrop" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop & Save" OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="XCoordinate" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                        <input id="YCoordinate" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                        <input id="Width" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                        <input id="Height" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
```

The code if necessary is as below :

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        //Check if Fileupload control has file in it
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            // Get selected image extension
            extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
            //Check image is of valid type or not
            if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".png" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".bmp")
            {
                //Cretae unique name for the file
                fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension;
                //Create path for the image to store
                filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images"), fileName);
                //Save image in folder
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
                //Show the panel and load the uploaded image in image control.
                pnlCrop.Visible = true;
                imgToCrop.ImageUrl = "/Images/" + fileName;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Please select jpg, jpeg, png, gif or bmp file only";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Please select file to upload";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Oops!! error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        extension = string.Empty;
        fileName = string.Empty;
        filePath = string.Empty;
    }
}

protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string croppedFileName = string.Empty;
    string croppedFilePath = string.Empty;
    //get uploaded image name
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(imgToCrop.ImageUrl);
    //get uploaded image path
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fileName);

    //Check if file exists on the path i.e. in the UploadedImages folder.
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        //Get the image from UploadedImages folder.
        System.Drawing.Image orgImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
        //Get user selected cropped area
        //Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0:0.##}", YCoordinate.Value)),

        Rectangle areaToCrop = new Rectangle(
            Convert.ToInt32(XCoordinate.Value),
            Convert.ToInt32(YCoordinate.Value),
            Convert.ToInt32(Width.Value),
            Convert.ToInt32(Height.Value));
        try
        {

            Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(areaToCrop.Width, areaToCrop.Height);
            //Create graphics object for alteration
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                //Draw image to screen
                g.DrawImage(orgImg, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height), areaToCrop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            //name the cropped image
            croppedFileName = "crop_" + fileName;
            //Create path to store the cropped image
            croppedFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), croppedFileName);
            //save cropped image in folder
            bitMap.Save(croppedFilePath);
            orgImg.Dispose();
            bitMap = null;
            //Now you can delete the original uploaded image from folder                
            File.Delete(filePath);
            //Hide the panel
            pnlCrop.Visible = false;
            //Show success message in label
            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblMsg.Text = "Image cropped and saved successfully";

            //Show cropped image
            imgCropped.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + croppedFileName;
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportsActiveConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spLogo", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogoPath", "Images/" + croppedFileName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //Show Reset button
            btnReset.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Oops!! error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            fileName = string.Empty;
            filePath = string.Empty;
            croppedFileName = string.Empty;
            croppedFilePath = string.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? You must be getting the error at `Rectangle areaToCrop = ` line, and if this code is inside contentplaceholder, then your master page must be having a form tag and that's enough.

Comment: yes i get the error "input string is not in correct format" in that line

Comment: Thats what i am saying,when i remove the form tag from above code,it throws the error.When i paste the above code in a page that doesnt have a masterpage and contentplaceholder, it works. But i want to use the code in a page that has a masterpage as well contentplaceholder

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is conversion from `XCoordinate.Value`,`XCoordinate.Value` etc. value to an `integer`. You should be cautious while doing conversions which can have non-integer values in supplied string.

Use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) Instead:-

```
int xCoordinate;
if(int.TryParse(XCoordinate.Value,out xCoordinate)
      //your code
```

**Edit:**
This error occurs when conversion fails from a string to an integer, TryParse method will return true if conversion is successful otherwise false and if conversion is successful, it assigns the converted value to output variable we have passed in method (`xCoordinate` in this case).

```
int xCoordinate,yCoordinate,width,height;
if(int.TryParse(XCoordinate.Value,out xCoordinate) && 
    int.TryParse(YCoordinate.Value,out yCoordinate) &&
    int.TryParse(Width.Value,out width) && int.TryParse(Height.Value,out height))
{
     Rectangle areaToCrop = new Rectangle(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,width,height)
}
else
{
     //Throw error, use any default values etc.
}
```

Comment: then how is it working on a page that doesnt have a masterpage?

Comment: I am not sure how to implement the above in my code for all co-ordinates.Please help me with that

Comment: @RelatedRhymes - I am not sure why it is not working with master page, but the reason for this issue is conversion only, please check my update and you can refer to MSDN documentation for more.

Comment: I am not able to use your method in my code.please help me out to try it once.Can you paste the entire method here? using my code.Pretty please

Comment: @RelatedRhymes -  Check now.

Comment: I get this error now 'The name 'areaToCrop' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Yes i did that.Now it doesnt throw any error and doesnt show any image in CroppedImage as well.I guess i have to find some other option now.

Comment: It depends on what you've written in the else block...try to put some message there to confirm if the parsing is happening correctly.

Comment: I did that too and it doesnt get into the else block..and doesnt even show the image.

Comment: @RelatedRhymes - Hey you are the best person to tell what's wrong cz you can only debug the code, please check where is is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate your aspx `input` with id `XCoordinate` into your master page the id of the input changes form `XCoordinate` to `ContentPlaceHolder1_XCoordinate`. Because of this problem the hidden input gets no value and hence your back-end code is not able to parse the empty string to Int.

Try and replace your script to this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#<%= imgToCrop.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
            onSelect: updateCoords
        });
    });

    function updateCoords(c) {
        jQuery('#<%= XCoordinate.ClientID %>').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#<%= YCoordinate.ClientID %>').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#<%= Width.ClientID %>').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#<%= Height.ClientID %>').val(c.h);
    };
```

Comment: still the same error.However,its not in the masterpage,it is in a webform that has a masterpage.

Comment: @Bhavik - I agree that the client id will change like the way you have demonstrated, but it has nothing to do with OP's error message as he is working on server side code and  not client side code!